# Can urls in a RESTful web service do different things for users with different authorization levels?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I am creating a RESTful webservice and I have a URL like this:

```
GET /pets
```

For normal users this should only return the pets that belongs to that user. But for admin it should return all pets in the system. Is this wrong to do? Or should I instead do this

```
GET /pets?ownedBy=Smith
```

and only allow access to the pets if the user is either Smith or an admin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think REST specifications mentions anything about it specifically. But IMPO, I believe it is perfectly right to return the results as per the requesting user. URLs should be kept as cleaner as possible. If user information is already present as part of headers, then it is not required to provide it in URL redundantly.

Answer (score 3):

While answer from Juned Ahsan is perfectly correct IMHO, I would probably modify your URLs pattern to something like

GET /Smith/pets : return pets for Mr Smith

Authorization can now be done one layer up in the URL and URLs always represent the same resource. I tend to prefer this solution because it will be easier to add a caching layer on top of it. Adding the user (from HTTP header) to the cache key is not efficient, nor is it easy to configure for some caching solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would only provide it in the URL if you also have cases where it is valid to put someone else's name there. For example if people are able to see their friends pet or if and admin is able to see a selected person's pets.

So in the situation where you have a user for that parameter it would make sense to expose it and always use it.

If that is not the case though then simplicity in your API is generally a good thing.

To answer the "can" in your question as well as the "should" though - it's entirely possible. Exactly how to implement it would depend on the framework you are using but they will all support this.

Answer (score 1):

These two URLs are different.

The first one gives a list of pets.

The second one gives also a list of pets, but in this case the list is filtered by the property "owner".There is nothing wrong with this. I would change the second URL slightly to:

```
GET /pets?owner=Smith
```

The key with that this URL is, that the type of the result is the same (a list of pet entities), and the meaning is the same too. There is only a filter applied to the list. That is where the query is made for in REST.

In some cases a Path parameter would be better. If you have entities "person", which do have a property of type list of pets, I would create a path like

```
/<user>/pets
```

If the list of pets are the root elements I would use a query.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is up to the implementation in the back-end service. Currently, I am working in a similar fashion on a WCF RESTful service (although for Android). And if you have some roles that you can add in your database, it is not so difficult to apply that in your service, and your url would have nothing to do with that.

Edit: If you do want to have something in the URL, you can always add that. But I do not think that it is necessary at all. The less the users see, the better.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier by Christian Kuetbach using REST you would pass parameters separated by /
i.e. `/<userid>/pets` if you have any other user specific functionality, or maybe other way around `/pets/<userid>`. I would suggest using UUID as userID - this way it will ensure user details security